# Patch Mixed HTML and XML Elements in the same Document with Object.setPrototype()

Tags: javascript, html, xml, browser, element

Suppose I move an element from an `XMLDocument` to an `HTMLDocument`:

```js
// create XML doc
const xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, 'my-root');

// reference the XML element
const myRoot = xmlDoc.childNodes[0];

// move to this HTML doc
document.body.appendChild(myRoot);

myRoot instanceof Element;     // true
myRoot instanceof HTMLElement; // false

myRoot.setAttribute('style', '...'); // doesn't render styles

// try to patch it
Object.getPrototypeOf(myRoot); // Element
Object.setPrototypeOf(myRoot, HTMLUnknownElement.prototype);
Object.getPrototypeOf(myRoot); // HTMLUnknownElement

myRoot.style;                        // error, illegal invocation
myRoot.setAttribute('style', '...'); // still doesn't render styles
```

Since `myRoot` is a `Node`, it participates in DOM tree can be queried for, etc. It also has all attribute-related functionality from `Element`.

But:

- it is missing all style-related functionality from `HTMLElement`
- it cannot be upgraded to a Custom Element
- after a serialize/deserialize round it will become an `HTMLUnknownElement`
- `setPrototypeOf` appears to work at first, but `style` property fails
- even after setting the prototype, any `style` attribute changes don't render

Why does accessing `style` break after setting the prototype?
Why does styling not work after setting the prototype?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want here. Is it just for your personal knowledge, you are curious why setting the JS prototype doesn't really change the underlying DOM element? Or are you trying to make your element behave like an HTMLElement because you need this in your code? If the latter, do you know about the [`Document.adoptNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/adoptNode) method?

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to understand what rules apply when mixing HTML and XML elements. The browser seems to allow me to do so freely but I can't get the XML elements to behave like HTML ones even after setting the prototype. `appendChild()`, already calls `adopt` internally https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-insert (step 7.1).

Comment: You are right about adoptNode, my bad. For why the DOM element is still not a true HTMLElement it's because what you have access to is just a JS wrapper over the DOM node. Changing the prototype of this wrapper won't change the underlying DOM node.

Comment: I'm guessing the style has to do with the ElementCSSInlineStyle mixin (https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-elementcssinlinestyle-mixin) being applied separately from the prototype. Is there any practical use to mixing HTML and XML nodes like this, besides SVG?